# Getting Syntax error with Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a simple keylogger using Python2.7 and am getting a SyntaxError for this piece of code:

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s'
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
```

Once I type this it says invalid Syntax and highlights the `chr` next to `(event.Ascii)

If you can answer this THANK YOU!

(PS in the preview the code was set up line by line correctly)

Comment: When I properly formatted your question (use 4 spaces before code when posting on stackoverflow) the reason it gives you a Syntaxerror becomes apparent immediately. Check the end of the previous line for a missing parentheses. I suggest to use an editor with builtin syntax highlighting to see these mistakes easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s') # missing )
    chr(event.Ascii)
```